# how to create a xmllist variable in flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, action

I am trying to create a xmllist variable in action script like this:

```
var _menuData:XMLList;              
                <menuitem label="File">
                    <menuitem label="Backup Schedule"/>
                    <menuitem label="Restore Schedule"/>                    
                </menuitem>
                <menuitem label="Edit">
                    <menuitem label="Cut"/>
                    <menuitem label="Copy"/>
                </menuitem>
```

How do I assign this xml to _menuDAta in actionScript?
I dont want to create a string first and then do it all by fixing line break errors. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see your code here but here is a sample code for creating an XMLList:

```
var xml:XML = <items><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>3</item></items>;
var xmlList:XMLList = xml.item;
trace(xmlList);
```

Hope it helps,
Rob

Comment: I have uncovered the source code in the question, so that you can update your answer.

Comment: Thanks Rob,but is there not a direct way of creating XMLList variable? I mean whithout having to add xml variable to list every time? thanks.

Comment: It seems like you can't populate an XMLList just like that :(

Comment: I can... either make an array of xml elements first and cast it to XMLList or simply make a root node of XMLList and then create xml variable by taking using it's children() property.

Answer (score -2):

```
var xmlList:XMLList = <><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>3</item></>;
trace(xmlList);
```

Comment: Adding some explanation along with the code would make this answer better.

Comment: and how does it differ or improve on the old answer